Flatlist scrollTo triggers onMomentumScrollEnd
Using Flatlists in my project, I've noticed that the onMomentumScrollEnd event handler gets triggered when I programmatically scroll with scrollTo even when the animated property is false.
Intuitively, I wouldn't have thought that onMomentumScrollEnd would be triggered as there is no momentum without animation, so I wondered if this is the expected behaviour. I tried looking around through the docs but couldn't find much on this.
